# OpenCV Error -215 while using Stitcher class with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I use stitcher to join images.But I got the error -215 as flollows:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (The data should normally be NULL!) in NumpyAllocator::allocate, file ..\..\..\opencv-3.1.0\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp, line 163
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/PyProjects/prj0826/082601.py", line 7, in <module>
result = stitcher.stitch((img1, img2))
cv2.error: ..\..\..\opencv-3.1.0\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:163: error: (-215) The data should normally be NULL! in function NumpyAllocator::allocate
```

I don't know what it means "data should normally be NULL".Here is my code:

```
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher()
img1 = cv2.imread("E:\\cube1.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("E:\\cube2.png")
result = stitcher.stitch((img1, img2))
```

Comment: There are lots of hits for this here and on the greater internet for this exact error message. Did you go through those first? If so, you should say so, and say how your situation differs from those.

Comment: Yes. I've got the answer.This is a bug in OpenCV 3.x.It's ok while using C++.